# Django query sum decimal based on column

Tags: python, sql, django

I trie to find a solution to summary fields depended on a row. In the database the SQL would be:

Database:

```
ACCOUNT | LIMIT   | MARKET | LENDING | BALANCE
----------------------------------------------
1000010 | 200.00  | 0.00   | -234.55 | 1000.00
1000010 | 300.00  | 11.00  | 0.00    | -239.00
1000010 | -200.00 | 235.00 | -134.00 | 450.00
1000011 | 30.00   | 1.00   | -10.00  | -98.00
1000011 | -200.00 | 235.00 | -134.00 | 49.00
```

SQL statements:

```
SUM(LIMIT) as bond_limit,
SUM(MARKET) as market_value,
SUM(LENDING) as lending_value,
SUM(case when BALANCE > 0 then BALANCE else 0 end) as FREE,
SUM(case when BALANCE < 0 then BALANCE else 0 end) as MISS
```

This should be the result:

```
ACCOUNT | LIMIT   | MARKET | LENDING | BOND_LIMIT | MARKET_VALUE | LENDING_VALUE | FREE | MINUS 
1000010 | 200.00  | 0.00   | -234.55 | Sum(LIMIT) | Sum(MARKET)  | Sum(LENDING)  | Sum(BALANCE) or 0
1000010 | 300.00  | 11.00  |    0.00 | Sum(LIMIT) | Sum(MARKET)  | Sum(LENDING)  | Sum(BALANCE) or 0
1000010 | -200.00 | 235.00 | -134.00 | Sum(LIMIT) | Sum(MARKET)  | Sum(LENDING)  | Sum(BALANCE) or 0
1000011 | 30.00   | 1.00   | -10.00  | Sum(LIMIT) | Sum(MARKET)  | Sum(LENDING)  | Sum(BALANCE) or 0
1000011 | -200.00 | 235.00 | -134.00 | Sum(LIMIT) | Sum(MARKET)  | Sum(LENDING)  | Sum(BALANCE) or 0
```

```
erg = database.objects.filter(
    account=ACCOUNT
).aggregate(
    bond_limit=Sum('LIMIT'),
    market_value=Sum('MARKET'),
    lending_value=Sum('LENDING')
)

.filter(bond_limit=bond_limit).aggregate(bond_limit=Sum('LIMIT')
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'bond_limit' is not defined
```

```
erg.filter(BALANCE__gt=0)... <= I have no Idea
```

Comment: You can make 2 queries and `union` them
query1 : filter BALANCE > 0
query2 : filter BALANCE < 0
```
erg = query1 | query2
```

Comment: The problem is I get the error message above Name Error: 'bond_number' is not defined